# useContext with useRef and useState

Tags: reactjs

I have written a function(last code snippet) that hides the input search if the user clicks anywhere outside of the input search.

What I'm trying to do now is when it hides, it should also clear out the text inside the input. I have tried useState and passing as an argument, I've tried useContext. However nothing I try seems to be working.

App.js file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

// Components
import Header from './Components/Header.js';

// Globals
import { GlobalContext } from './Globals/GlobalContext.js';

const App =() => {
  // Variables
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  // Render
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>LOG</title>
      </Helmet>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ searchText, setSearchText }}>
        <Header />
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js file

```
import React from 'react';

// Components
import HeaderTop from './HeaderComponents/HeaderTop.js';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <HeaderTop />
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

HeaderTop.js file

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

// Globals
import { GlobalContext } from '../../Globals/GlobalContext.js';
import { useComponentVisible } from '../../Globals/index.js';

const HeaderTop = () => {
  // Variables
  const evSearchBtnName = "open-close-search-btn";
  const { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible } = useComponentVisible(false, evSearchBtnName);
  const { searchText, setSearchText } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  // functions
  const searchSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Use \"" + searchText + "\" for search library");
  }
  // Render
  return (
    <div className="div-header-content-top">
      <div className="div-header-top-left">
        <h1>LOG</h1>
        <div className="div-header-top-left-search-icon" name={evSearchBtnName} onClick={() => (setIsComponentVisible(!isComponentVisible))} />
        <form onSubmit={ev => searchSubmit(ev)}>
          <div ref={ref} style={isComponentVisible ? {width: "100%"} : {width: "0", overflow: "hidden"}}>
            <input type="search" name="searchText" placeholder="search..." onChange={ev => setSearchText(ev.target.value)} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name={evSearchBtnName} />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HeaderTop;
```

Globals/index.js file

```
import { useComponentVisible } from "./Functions.js";

export { useComponentVisible }
```

Globals/Functions.js file

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from 'react';

// Globals
import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalContext.js';

const useComponentVisible = (initialIsVisible, evTriggerBtnName="default-trg-btn") => {
  const { setSearchText } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible] = useState(initialIsVisible);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (ref.current && isComponentVisible && !ref.current.contains(event.target) && (event.target.name ? event.target.name !== evTriggerBtnName : event.target.getAttribute('name') !== evTriggerBtnName)) {
      setSearchText(''); // <-------------------------- this is not working
      setIsComponentVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isComponentVisible]);

  return { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible };
}

export { useComponentVisible }
```

anyone have any idea why `setSearchText('');` is not working in the last code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use your `Context` inside `useComponentVisible` `custom hook` since it does not actually being **wrapped** with:-

```js
<GlobalContext.Provider value={{ searchText, setSearchText }}>
  <Header />
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

**try both way**

- don't know which one will work for you though

#### Opt 1

So, instead of just:-

- passing `fields` of `false, evSearchBtnName` and,
- calling & import `const { setSearchText } = useContext(GlobalContext);` directly in your `custom hook`

Why don't you ():-

- pass the `setSearchText` to your `custom hook`
- in `HeaderTop.js`

```js
const HeaderTop = () => {
  const { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible } = useComponentVisible(false, evSearchBtnName, setSearchText);
  
  return ()
}
```

- in `Globals/Functions.js`:-

```js
const useComponentVisible = (initialIsVisible, evTriggerBtnName="default-trg-btn", setSeacrhText) => {
  // don't need this anymore then
  // const { setSearchText } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // ...something
}
```

#### Opt 2

- create new `state` in `useComponentVisible` `custom hook` and
- and use `useEffect` in `HeaderTop.js` to detect changes in **said** `state`
- in `Globals/Functions.js`:-

```js
// Globals
import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalContext.js';

const useComponentVisible = (initialIsVisible, evTriggerBtnName="default-trg-btn") => {
  const [searchText2, setSearchText2] = useState(''); // new custom state
  const [isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible] = useState(initialIsVisible);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (ref.current && isComponentVisible && !ref.current.contains(event.target) && (event.target.name ? event.target.name !== evTriggerBtnName : event.target.getAttribute('name') !== evTriggerBtnName)) {
      setSearchText2(''); // <-------------------------- this is not working
      setIsComponentVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isComponentVisible]);

  return { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible, searchText2};
}

export { useComponentVisible }
```

- in `HeaderTop.js`:-

```js
const HeaderTop = () => {
  // Variables
  const evSearchBtnName = "open-close-search-btn";
  const { ref, isComponentVisible, setIsComponentVisible, searchText2 } = useComponentVisible(false, evSearchBtnName);
  const { searchText, setSearchText } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  // apply changes in searchText2
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchText(searchText2)
  }, [searchText2])

  // functions
  const searchSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Use \"" + searchText + "\" for search library");
  }
  // Render
  return (
    <div className="div-header-content-top">
      <div className="div-header-top-left">
        <h1>LOG</h1>
        <div className="div-header-top-left-search-icon" name={evSearchBtnName} onClick={() => (setIsComponentVisible(!isComponentVisible))} />
        <form onSubmit={ev => searchSubmit(ev)}>
          <div ref={ref} style={isComponentVisible ? {width: "100%"} : {width: "0", overflow: "hidden"}}>
            <input type="search" name="searchText" placeholder="search..." onChange={ev => setSearchText(ev.target.value)} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name={evSearchBtnName} />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HeaderTop;
```

Comment: I've tried both options, but neither is clearing the text for me. What I also tried before was a little combo of both options. Basically I used useState in the component file and tried passing it through the argument in the function from the function file. But that didn't work either. I know the body is being iterated because I can throw in a `console.log()` and it is logging to the console. I'm really missing redux where things just worked (even if it took 4x longer to create a variable)

Comment: wow... I figured it out. I was missing the `value={searchText}` in `<input type="search" name="searchText" placeholder="search..." onChange={ev => setSearchText(ev.target.value)} value={searchText} />`.